# how to query max value in column with php sqlite3?

Tags: php, sqlite

I am not able to get max value from SQLite with PHP but getting 0 (zero) but If I run the query in SQLite I am getting COrrect value. The code is shown below.

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
  function __construct() {
     $this->open('data.db');
  }
}
$con = new MyDB();

  $sql = "SELECT MAX(sd_id) FROM stu_data ORDER BY sd_id DESC LIMIT 1";
  $result = $con->query($sql);
  if ($result) {   
      if($row = $result->fetchArray(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $lclId = $row[0]["MAX(sd_id)"] + 1;
          $lclNo = $lclId;
      }
  } else {
$lclNo = '1';
}
```

Here I am Getting $row[0]["sd_id"] AS zero (0) always.

Comment: $row[0]["sd_id"] it means you are try to get 0 number index so make that dynamic. if you get more results in $row.

Comment: write the output of `var_dump($row);`

Comment: `SELECT MAX(sd_id) FROM stu_data` returns only 1 row with only i column, so the rest: `ORDER BY sd_id DESC LIMIT 1` is useless.

Comment: _“Here I am Getting $row[0]["sd_id"] AS zero (0) always.”_ - you would probably get a warning from PHP that this index doesn’t exist, if only you had proper PHP error reporting enabled. (Which you should go do _now_ first of all.) And checking what $row actually contains could have also helped.

Comment: I need to get only one row with max value from the column.

Comment: @misorude I am not getting any warning or any other thing.

Comment: Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled, or not? And what did you see when you just did a `var_dump($row);`, as already suggested?

Comment: I got my answer below I will update.

Answer (score 1):

Your return value is not called `sd_id` as you have not aliased the value. You can either use

```
$row['MAX(sd_id)']
```

or better yet supply a column alias in the query:

```
SELECT MAX(sd_id) AS max_sd_id FROM stu_data
```

Then you can refer to it as `$row['max_sd_id']`. e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(sd_id) AS max_sd_id FROM stu_data ORDER BY sd_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result) {   
    if($row = $result->fetchArray(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $lclId = $row['max_sd_id'] + 1;
        $lclNo = $lclId;
    }
} else {
    $lclNo = '1';
}
```

Note that the `ORDER BY sd_id DESC LIMIT 1` in your query is meaningless as it will only return 1 value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
  function __construct() {
  $this->open('data.db');
 }
}
$con = new MyDB();

$sql = "SELECT MAX(sd_id) FROM stu_data ORDER BY sd_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result) {   
  if($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
      $lclId = $row[0]["MAX(sd_id)"] + 1;
      $lclNo = $lclId;
  }
} else {
$lclNo = '1';
}
```

The Difference is Need to use fetchArray(**SQLITE3_ASSOC**) Instead of **fetchArray(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)**